# Link a systemd template unit to include in the search paths

Tags: systemd

On RH 7.9, witht systemd 219.

I have a template unit **dataDaemon@.service**, available where I deploy my app, in
`/opt/advdata/system/dataDaemon@.service`.

The [documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-systemctl/#lbAG) of the link command says

> link PATH...
>
> Link a unit file that is not in the unit file search paths into the unit file search path.

Below are my attempts:

```bash
$ systemctl link /opt/advdata/system/dataDaemon@.service
Failed to execute operation: Unit name dataDaemon@.service is missing the instance name.
$ systemctl link /opt/advdata/system/dataDaemon@src01.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
$ cd /opt/advdata/system/
$ ln -s dataDaemon@.service dataDaemon@src01.service
$ systemctl link /opt/advdata/system/dataDaemon@src01.service
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Is there a solution where I don't have to copy the file in a protected folder ?

My only solution for now seems to copy `/opt/advdata/system/dataDaemon@.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` and enable them from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution.

Files are expected to be in `/etc/systemd/system`.
For user services, you can put them in the user's home, but that's it.

From [systemd-unit man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-systemd.unit/), symlinks should target the same known search paths, and are only used for aliasing, not for redirecting.